# How to attach file extension with my AIR application that by default open with my AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I made an AIR application that parses some specific files. I am using flex builder 4.5 and SDK 3.6. I want to attach Icons with those files and when I double click those files they should open with my application. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not do this using SDK 3.6 in flex builder 4.5. To do this we need to use SDK 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Application Descriptor** file (look in your project structure for a file named like your application, plus -app.xml as an ending) find the tag **fileTypes**.
If you uncomment it, you can specify which file types you application handles, and which icons to show for those files.

Comment: I did this but when I package that it did not work. I add the file types one by one and specifies the Icons but it did not work. I am using SDK 3.6. The same thing works when I test using SDK 4.5.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 3.6 part. Unfortunately, I have no 3.6 installation at hand to test :(